# Apache 2.2 on Yosemite, anyone?

Tags: apache-http-server, osx-yosemite

I need to upgrade Mountain Lion AND keep Apache 2.2.

Does anyone know if it's possible to go back to Apache 2.2 after the upgrade or at least to have 2.2 alongside 2.4?
Apart using virtual machines, that will be my plan B...:-)

I'm trying to upgrade without loosing hours of productivity.

I need Apache 2.2 because of many virtual hosts, modules already working and because it reflectes the production configuration.

Comment: I just found this, no idea if it's working:  https://gist.github.com/falker/857c40ac854999d88135

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run two versions of Apache side-by-side, just as long as they're not trying to bind to the same IP+port. Now, that being said, it would be kind of silly to do so if you don't have to. So, first thing, I would back up all of your *.conf files. Second, I would try your config files on 2.4, or at least try to identify if there are any incompatibilities between your config between 2.2 and 2.4 changes ([see changes here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)).

If it does break, and you need to run 2.2, you can easily download, compile and install 2.2 to any destination you'd like. (e.g. not /usr/sbin) That way, you can run both versions concurrently (or deactivate 2.4 with apachectl if you're not using it).